# ASDoc: how to include all classes (and only those classes) in a package without manually specifying them?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, asdoc

The task is simple, I need to document a dozen of ActionScript / Flex classes in a certain package and there are "only" two requirements:

1. **Only those classes should be documented**, no classes from other packages.
2. **I don't want to manually enumerate all the classes**, that creates a maintenance burden (need to update the ASDoc script whenever new classes are added or removed from the package).

`-doc-sources` will allow me to specify a path to a package directory which is good for the second point but will make the first point hard to achieve as `-exclude-dependencies` option throws an error when `-doc-sources` method is used.

The other way to specify which classes to document is `-source-path` + `-doc-classes` but `-doc-classes` doesn't support wildcards so I don't think I can throw a package on it.

The third way is to use `-doc-namespaces` but that expects an XML file with all the classes enumerated manually so that doesn't help either.

Is there a way to achieve my "simple" task with the current implementation of ASDoc?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the @private keyword for classes you don't want documented?  Just put it in an ASDoc comment above the class definition.

Comment: I want them documented in other builds, just not in this one.

Comment: Understood.  I think you'll have to manually specify them.  [Or modify ASDocs to do what you want..  I think the ASDoc is in Apache Flex]

Comment: A workaround is to scan the directory using a shell script and use the result as a -doc-classes parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use [-package name"description"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSd0ded3821e0d52fe1e63e3d11c2f44bc36-7ffa.html)

Comment: This describes the package, not the classes inside it.

Comment: @Borek oh, so what about giving the exact path of your package root. By definition all the classes belong to the package should be there. And tell make the rest as library sources that you can tell the tool to ignore